# How to scan all files in a folder, including subfolders in VC++ 2008?

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, directory, visual-c++-2008

I'm want to build an application in VC++ 2008 (Windows form application).

Here I want to browse a folder of my choice (push button "browse"), such that when I press the "scan" button my application will find all the files in the folder I chose, including subfolders. Then all files are placed in a listbox,  I have this code will be in c# not in c++, how to change my code in c++?

```
private void btnScan_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> search = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        progressBar1.Maximum = search.Count;
        //foreach (Directory.GetDirectories.search))

        foreach(string item in search)
        {
            try
             {
                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(item);
                string read = stream.ReadToEnd();
                foreach(string st in viruslist)
                {
                if(Regex.IsMatch(read,st))
                {
                viruses+=1;
                    label1.Text+= viruses;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
                }
                progressBar1.Increment(1);
                }

             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {

             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That does depend on whether you trying to create a managed C++ CLR application or a native Windows C++ Win32 application. If it is managed you can use .Net. If not you will need to use Win32 or a Win32 wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your have a .NET application ( since you are using Windows Forms) the easiest way is to use [System::IO::Directory::GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx#Y0) list all of the files in a folder and all subfolders.

```
array<String^>^ files = GetFiles(folder, "*.*", System::IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
```

The AllDirectories option causes GetFiles to search for files in all sub folders.

Comment: yes, i mean like this code, but Can you tell me the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

This code might work....

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct SearchFile
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> FileNameArray;
    FileNameArray files;

    FileNameArray::iterator begin()
    {
        return files.begin();
    }

    FileNameArray::iterator end()
    {
        return files.end();
    }

    int count() const
    {
        return (int)files.size();
    }

    std::string operator[](int index)
    {
        return files[index];
    }

    void operator()(const std::string &path, const std::string &pattern)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
        HANDLE hf;
        std::string findwhat;
        std::vector<std::string> dir;

        findwhat = path + "\\*";  // directory

        hf = FindFirstFile(findwhat.c_str(), &wfd);
        while (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            if (wfd.cFileName[0] != '.' && (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                std::string found;

                found = path + "\\" + wfd.cFileName;
                dir.push_back(found);
            }

            if (!FindNextFile(hf, &wfd))
            {
                FindClose(hf);
                hf = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            }
        }

        findwhat = path + "\\" + pattern;  // files

        hf = FindFirstFile(findwhat.c_str(), &wfd);
        while (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            if (wfd.cFileName[0] != '.' && !(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                std::string found;

                found = path + "\\" + wfd.cFileName;
                files.push_back(found);
            }

            if (!FindNextFile(hf, &wfd))
            {
                FindClose(hf);
                hf = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            }
        }

        // continue with directories
        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = dir.begin(); it != dir.end(); ++it)
            this->operator()(*it, pattern);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    SearchFile sf;

    // get all .jpg files in current dir
    sf(".", "*.jpg");

    for (int i = 0; i != sf.count(); ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", sf[i].c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes it work, but i want to use windows application not a console application...can you help me?thanks

Comment: @mapix just simply copy the SearchFile struct into your win32 app project and use it like what i did in the console app. perhaps you'll have to change some string manipulations if you're using UNICODE.

Answer (score 0):

Use findfirst and findnext () to implement. check below msdn link for more details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzxfzac(v=vs.71).aspx